# IntelliJ Idea: How to run Spring Boot application which has a main class in the external dependency?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am normally able to [run a Spring Boot application](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-boot.html#run-a-spring-boot-application) (see the screen) if I am the one who defines the main class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.

[image]

Once I, however, have an extension module with a bunch of bean definitions and configurations, and the main class annotated by `@SpringBootApplication` is in an external dependency imported by Maven, then I am unable to locate such a class in the Run/Debug Configuration as it does not exist in my code-base. Let's name such a class `com.mycompany.WhateverApplication`.

On K8s, the application runs normally because of the Maven Spring Boot plugin that repackages the whole application.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
        <mainClass>com.mycompany.WhateverApplication</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

How to run the application from IntelliJ Idea and how to create a valid Run/Debug Configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not direct solution provided by IntelliJ Idea, but I found two workarounds.

### Run the erroneous configuration anyway

As long as the main class annotated by `@SpringBootApplication` is present on the classpath, typing the class name into the Spring Boot Run/Debug Configuration should work, though IntelliJ Idea marks the configuration as incomplete or erroneous.

[image]

Though it is not beautiful and the configuration icon looks scary, the application boots up: [image]

---

### Extend the class

A more elegant solution is actually just extending the main class annotated by `@SpringBootApplication` to make it visible for IntelliJ Idea. In fact, nothing would change effectively for the application start-up and the Maven Spring Boot plugin does not need to (but can) be changed.

```java
package com.mycompany;

import com.mycompany.WhateverApplication;

public class ExtWhateverApplication extends WhateverApplication {

}
```

Now the application can be run directly from IntelliJ Idea as well as the Run/Debug Configuration. I recommend putting the new class in the same-named package as its parent.

[image]

[image]

---

**Note**: In both cases, make sure the classpath `-cp` points to the extension module you want to run.

Comment: You screenshots are not clear, can you please update them with good resolutions

Comment: @csf Done......